# Please reopen questions that I improved?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

Can the closed questions beneath (now edited and improved) please be reopened? I welcome recommendations for  improvement! Thanks.

[How do I tactfully tell a superior that a junior employee continually provides wrong information?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/69814/22656)
[How can I tactfully insist on communicating with someone senior, not someone more junior?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/86789/22656)
[How can I tactfully write that any response confirms receiving a previous email?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/57435/22656)

To explicitly answer [this saddening comment](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5203/please-reopen-questions-that-i-improved/5215?noredirect=1#comment15283_5215), I answer its quoted questions beneath.

> "What is your position ?"

I edited my posts to state that I volunteer at a charity where I help laypeople.

> Are S1 and S2 at the same level?

I removed all references to S1 and S2. So my edits don't answer this.

> I think the nature of the problem is critical here. Is this job-related, or a personal issue?

Job-related.

> Are you a customer of the company? Or the company is a customer of yours?

I'm helping customers of the company.

> Is this person your boss, a coworker, or a customer? Why do you need confirmation of receipt? Why aren't email read-receipts working?

The other person is the government. I need confirmation of receipt because the government has alleged not receiving documents. I don't send read-receipts, as they can be judged intrusive.

Answer (score 4):

It appears your edits have mostly reworded the closed questions. You are yet to resolve the issues led to the closure. Please address the issues, we will consider them for reopening.

A common observation across the three questions is your attempts to be as vague and anonymous as possible are making the questions unclear and confusing.

As DarkCygnus says, you should use [reopen-request](/questions/tagged/reopen-request) for one question per post. However, since this post is already made, I will comment on each of them.

---

> How do I tactfully tell someone that someone else continually provides wrong information?

You have not provided your position with respect to this "someone". Several users have pointed out that this information is essential to answer your question.

- > Are you a client ? the same company ? What is your position ? – Gautier C Jun 15 '16 at 12:05
- > Are S1 and S2 at the same level? Some kind of matrix management? Or is S2 superior to S1? – Andrew Leach Jun 15 '16 at 13:02
- > I think the nature of the problem is critical here. Is this job-related, or a personal issue? – psubsee2003 Jun 15 '16 at 13:14
- > I will vote to reopen the question and will very likely post an answer after the role of S2 was properly clarified. – Philipp Jun 15 '16 at 14:15

---

> How can I tactfully insist on communicating with someone senior, not someone more junior?

Same as above.

- > Are you a customer of the company? Or the company is a customer of yours? The answer makes a big difference for the answer to your question. If you are a customer, you have the right to ask for the person who can resolve the problem. If the company is a customer of yours, you have no right to interfere with their business decision. – scaaahu Mar 13 '17 at 3:34

---

> How can I tactfully write that any response constitutes confirmation?

Some users have discussed your question and possible solutions in comments, but David's comment describes why the question was closed.

- > All of your attempts to generalize and anonymize your question make it more vague and confusing. Please add more detail and tell us what exactly your situation is. Is this person your boss, a coworker, or a customer? Why do you need confirmation of receipt? Why aren't email read-receipts working? As it stands, I'm voting to close this question as unclear. – David K Nov 10 '15 at 13:34

Comment: Many thanks. I've again edited and detailed these 3 questions: better now?  Please recommend more improvements if necessary.

Comment: You are not making any attempt at all to address the issues raised in the comments and now also here in meta. At this point, I am finding it very hard to believe you are not doing this deliberately. I have flagged your questions for mod attention, and won't be engaging any further on this topic.

Comment: "At this point, I am finding it very hard to believe you are not doing this deliberately." I'm very saddened to read this, when I am trying to "address the issues". Can you please read my post overhead? I edited it to answer your quoted questions individually.

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware that most of those posts took place months if not years ago?

I see some that date back to 2015 and other to 2017. Also most of them have a negative score, even below the "-3 zone" (which in my experience is most of the times irreversible).

I suggest that, in any case you **try to rephrase them and post them again in a more clear and on-topic manner**, in case they weren't answered already.

Maybe we can end up opening them, but it will hardly have any purpose or benefits now (you already got and even accepted some answers there, suggesting your question was satisfied).

I see that only 2 of those didn't received an answer, so perhaps you should focus on them and post them again now you have written them properly.

I also suggest that in future situations you post for a [reopen-request](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reopen-request) of a *single question*, instead of a whole bunch of them. This makes it easier to address and solve the problems it may have.

Comment: Thanks. I have rephrased them already?

Comment: Yes, but given the circumstances it will have less effect than posting them again (not reopen)