# How can I tactfully write that I haven't received a reply?: Why was this deleted by 3 users?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I improved the post after [its closure on Apr 11](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/110418/22656),  but I'm not sure if the improvements were contemplated? It was then deleted by 3 users on May 16.

Comment: Downvoting this meta question doesn't help the user.  Typing stuff in a helpful manner helps the user.

Comment: @Snow seems that they keep coming ;/

Answer (score 3):

Surely they were contemplated, but if it was deleted then it means that they weren't enough to make it worthy of reopening. Have in mind that deleting is a 10k+ privilege (20K+ for enhanced privileges), so surely those experienced users had valid reasons for doing so.

Perhaps there were changes you made to it, but the main issues with the post revolve around what @Snow [answered](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5214/73791) on the last post you wrote.

Besides that, I must stress the fact that the question had a score around -7 which is *really* low and unlikely to recover (and get attention and useful answers) even though it were reopened/undeleted.

Like I suggested to you before on one of your posts: *If your post has really low score, users found it unclear or off topic, and even closed/deleted*, **you better repost the question again after addressing those issues.**

Think of it as "rebooting" your question, only this time it will be on topic, receive upvotes and good answers, and in general been given merit for what it is worth.

One may have the next potential HNQ, but if it has those faults in its content it won't get very far.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is here is that you're asking a question that's basically been asked many times before (how to chase up an email reply).  You need to make this one clearly different and precise to your situation to make it successful.

Suggested draft:

---

Title:  **How do I tactfully chase up a missing delivery sent to a government department?**

Part of my work is to process clients complaints and send them to a government department for processing on their behalf.

On May 1st, the courier confirmed delivery of one of these packages, but despite me chasing them up, they didn't respond until the 25th May where they claimed that they didn't receive the package.

If they had responded earlier, I could have resent the package and the complaint deadline would not have been at risk of expiring.

Repeatedly emailing the department did not seem to work as they were slow in responding.  How could I have dealt with this better so that I can in future serve my clients more effectively?

---

So, this wording clearly (I hope) offers the **key points** here:

- What my responsibility is (for the context of the question)
- What went wrong
- What I did to try and correct the situation
- How I would like to see this resolved

Bear in mind any obvious questions you'll be asked and have responses ready (or (better) work them into the question)

- Is this the first time you've used this courier?
- Is this a government-preferred courier? (if such a thing exists)
- Was there a recipient signature/name as a proof of delivery?
- Did you try phoning the government department? (as opposed to just emailing)
- Have you successfully submitted complaint packages many times in the past?
- Are there any government guidelines about submissions that you need to follow more precisely.

Comment: +1. Thank you. I edited my post again after pasting your rewrite (but not identically, as I added details).

Comment: If this won't take too much time, can you please suggest drafts for https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/99203/22656, https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/57435/22656, and https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/86789/22656 too? Please feel free to edit the questions directly. I can't spot what else can be improved?

Comment: Ok.  The first link you provided was the question we're talking about here.  The second link is the same question (so you can let that drop).  The third link, you just need to follow the **key points** above.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't intend [#2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/57435/22656) to be a duplicate. I reworded it now: can you see the distinction? I also edited [#3](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/86789/22656). Any other areas for improvement?

Answer (score 0):

I [edited](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/110418/9) the post to include your role (volunteer for a charity that processes clients' complaints) from your [other post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5203/3192). I have cast the 2nd undelete vote and [asked our 10K friends](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44864622#44864622) to have another look in the chat room.

Note: I was the first delete voter and the last close voter. I cast the delete vote on Apr 11, not May 16.

Comment: Thanks a lot! +1.